# How to refresh page when web page is rotated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next JSs, I'm having trouble finding a solution how to refresh the page when it's rotated

```
const app () => {

  useEffect(()=>{
  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    window.location.reload()
  });})

   return(<>some code</>);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the page when the orientation changes?

Comment: @Andy probably because some JS stuff doesn't detect width changes and only calculates sizes on page load. (That's my guess)

Comment: you can easily write those calculations in window resize.

Comment: @Andy 
Because one of the components, width and height are based on viewport, it doesn't follow when in rotation. I think it's easier to refresh than fix the code because this is not my code, I was given the task of fixing this code.

Comment: OP if you have a look around you'll find a hook called `useWindowResize` that you can add to your component, and based on its output you can update things and re-render, but you shouldn't need to reload the page.

Comment: Event _orientationchange_ is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event). Use [`screen.orientation.onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/onchange) instead.

Comment: *"I'm having trouble finding a solution how to refresh the page when it's rotated"* What is the trouble, exactly? Although there are issues with what you have above, I would expect that while it wouldn't be quite right, it would at least trigger a reload when the orientation changes. Doesn't that happen? What happens instead? Do you get an errors?

Comment: [Here's the one I use](https://jsfiddle.net/vtqdmpsc/). It returns an object with width/height properties, and you can add those to your effect dependency array, and then update the code that renders the component. No reload required. So `const windowSize = useWindowResize();`, and you'll have `windowSize.width`, and `windowSize.height` that you can check.

Comment: @Andy i use npm beautiful-react-hooks its work like charm,.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you **don't** do that.

But there are a couple of problems with your implementation of it:

1. To hook up an event listener on component mount, you need an empty dependency array on your `useEffect`. Otherwise, your effect callback is called on *every render* which, in your case, will add multiple handlers.
2. You aren't removing the handler when the component is unmounted. You should return a cleanup callback from the `useEffect` callback.
3. The `orientationchange` event is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event) and has [poor browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event#browser_compatibility). Instead, listen to [`change` on `Screen.orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/onchange) which has [better browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/onchange#browser_compatibility). Alternatively, just listen for [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event), since a change in screen orientation that you care about will trigger a `resize` event, and mobile devices are getting more and more sophisticated with how the screen real estate is used (split screen, etc.). It's possible not all of those would cause a change in orientation, but you seem to care about a change in *size*.

Separately, `app` isn't a valid component name. Component functions must start with a capital letter.

Fixing all of those:

```
const App () => {
    useEffect(()=>{
        const handler = () => {
            // Handle the change in orientation here (I recommend **not** reloading)
        };
        Screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", handler); // Or window resize
        return () => {
            // On unmount, remove the handler
            Screen.orientation.removeEventListener("change", handler); // Or window resize
        };
    }, []);
    // ^^−−−− tells `useEffect` to only call your callback once, when the component
    // is first mounted.

    return (<>some code</>);
}
```